# Delete Document in mongodb via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm storing data in mongodb and using mongoose to access and delete it. I have a schema Class with a no_of_student, school_id. I have successfully added document to it but i'm getting error while deleting a document.

> I have tried Model.remove function, Model.findbyIdAndRemove function and Model.findOneAndDelete to delete a document but it didn't working.
> It gives me a return message with ok:1 and deletedCount:0.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
const Class = require('../models/classes')

router.get('',(req,res,next)=>{
Class.find((err,classes)=>{
    res.json(classes)
})
})

router.post('',(req,res,next)=>{
let newClass = new Class({
    classes:req.body.classes,
    no_of_student:req.body.no_of_student,
    school_id:req.body.school_id
})

newClass.save((err,classes)=>{
    if(err){
        res.json("Failed to Add Class")
    }
    else if(classes){
        res.json("Class Added Successfully!")
    }
})
})

router.delete('/:id',(req,res,next)=>{
Class.deleteOne({_id:req.param.id},(err,result)=>{
    if(err){
        res.json(err)
    }
    else if(result){
        res.json(result)
    }
})
})

module.exports = router
```

Schema Code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Classes = mongoose.Schema({
classes :{
    type:Array,
},
no_of_student:{
    type:Number
},
school_id:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
}
})

const Class = module.exports = mongoose.model('Class',Classes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `req.params.id` instead of `req.param.id`